# This URL are not redirect to youtube but youtube API return a normal response

Tags: youtube-api

This URL are not redirect to youtube but youtube API return a normal response.

- https://www.google.com/#https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J5XYimlXzc
- https://www.google.com/?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J5XYimlXzc
- [https://www.google.com/\https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J5XYimlXzc](https://www.google.com/%5Chttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J5XYimlXzc)

I am curious to why normal responses are sent when invalid URLs like these.

Wouldn't a service that checks for valid URLs against the YouTube API are exposed to security issues?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com is YouTube UI, why do you state that YouTube API is involved? All these URLs *redirect* to https://www.google.com in my case.